# Creating function that returns table that isn't declared yet

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

Our product has several components that can be installed separately and supports oracle. But we do not grant `Create type` privilege. So during installation of one of the components, I need to ask customer to install the component, add `Create type` privilege and then run my component.

In the SQL file that will create functions I was planning to give following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_some_data (input INT)
    RETURN my_table
AS
    my_table_var   my_table := my_table ();
    ret_code       INT := 0;
BEGIN
    ret_code := create_my_type_and_table ();

    IF 1 = ret_code
    THEN
        NULL; -- add some data to my_table_var here
    END IF;

    RETURN my_table_var;
END get_some_data;
/
```

The function `create_my_type_and_table` would use `execute immediate` to create record and table type.

Obviously, the problem is since function `get_some_data` says it will return `my_table`, compilation fails.

I wanted to know:

- is there a way out?
- the reason why I want to create and return table is because I need to return multiple fields. All of them are int. Is there a way I can return multi dimensional array, perhaps system collection? I tried sys.odcinumberlist but I did not find a way by which I can return 4 columned sys.odcinumberlist.

Comment: Is returning a ref cursor an option? Otherwise, what will consume this - PL/SQL types *might* be an option, but it depends what you do with the table later.

Comment: Hello Alex, I would like to use the returned table as part of query that will use standard join and where clauses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some anonymous generic stuff, you could use `TABLE OF [TYPE]`.

Here an example how to build a `table of number` which is used by another type `"table of table of number"`.

Like every type, you can create them within your schema to use it between different plsql-blocks or return-value in functions.

```
declare
    TYPE tableOfNumber is Table of Number; -- Define a row of numbers
    TYPE tableOfTableOfNumer is Table of tableOfNumber; -- define a table of rows

    tableMaster tableOfTableOfNumer := tableOfTableOfNumer(); -- init tables
    tableChild1 tableOfNumber := tableOfNumber();
    tableChild2 tableOfNumber := tableOfNumber();
begin
    tableChild1.Extend; -- add a new number-field to our table 
    tableChild1(1) := 0; -- set the value to the new field
    tableChild1.Extend;
    tableChild1(2) := 1;
    tableChild2.Extend;
    tableChild2(1) := 2;
    tableChild2.Extend;
    tableChild2(2) := 3;
    tableMaster.Extend; -- add a new 'row' to out table
    tableMaster(1) := tableChild1; -- fill the new 'row' with the fields
    tableMaster.Extend;
    tableMaster(2) := tableChild2;

    -- loop through our 'table'
    for r in 1 .. tableMaster.Count
    LOOP
        for c in 1 .. tableMaster(r).Count
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(tableMaster(r)(c)); 
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
end;
```

If you want to create a function you have to:

#### 1. Declare types in you schema

(an grant rights to the users)

```
CREATE TYPE tableOfNumber AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
CREATE TYPE tableOftableOfNumber AS TABLE OF tableOfNumber;
```

#### 2. Create you function:

(here with same code like the plsql-block)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DINTER.MyFunction
RETURN tableOftableOfNumber
Is
    tableMaster tableOftableOfNumber := tableOftableOfNumber(); -- init tables
    tableChild1 tableOfNumber := tableOfNumber();
    tableChild2 tableOfNumber := tableOfNumber();
begin
    tableChild1.Extend; -- add a new number-field to our table 
    tableChild1(1) := 0; -- set the value to the new field
    tableChild1.Extend;
    tableChild1(2) := 1;
    tableChild2.Extend;
    tableChild2(1) := 2;
    tableChild2.Extend;
    tableChild2(2) := 3;
    tableMaster.Extend; -- add a new 'row' to out table
    tableMaster(1) := tableChild1; -- fill the new 'row' with the fields
    tableMaster.Extend;
    tableMaster(2) := tableChild2;

    RETURN tableMaster;

end MyFunction;
/
```

#### 3. Call the function:

```
declare
    tableMaster tableOfTableOfNumber;
begin
    tableMaster := myfunction();
    -- loop through our 'table'
    for r in 1 .. tableMaster.Count
    LOOP
        for c in 1 .. tableMaster(r).Count
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(tableMaster(r)(c)); 
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Hello Kara, how can I put the result of the query *int the type you created* and how can I use it in query *after it is returned*? Thanks.

Comment: @user28458: Added an example